Password Encryption and Syncing / Wordpress - Codeigniter 4
I have wordpress website which saves a user's password in database table field wp_users.user_pass.
On the other hand, I have an application programmed with Codeigniter 4 which saves new user's passwords using password_hash() and verifies user logins with the CI4 function password_verify(), which seems compatible with PHPs crypt() method.
I want to sync the wp_users database table into my app to have the user password from Wordpress so that wordpress users can log in to that app with the same userdata / password.
But the passwords seem to be stored into a different encryption format in both systems.
I don't understand the Wordpress programming good enough to find the solution.
What I've recognised is, that each time I put the same password for a user new in the wordpress admin interface, the saved password hash in the wp_users table is different.
I also can't find the code that saves the passwords in wordpress.
When I use wordpress' wp_hash_password() or crypt() or crypt_private() functions, I get never one of the saved hashed passwords.
How can I find out how the passwords are saved or how I can check after syncing in my own app, if the user enters the wordpress user's password?

I've found the solution: I've included the class-phppass.php from wordpress into my app and use its CheckPassword() function to verify the synced passwords, that works.
